# After CBCentralManager initialize centralManagerDidUpdateState it's not call

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm working on my first bluetooth app. For now i've an AppUIview that implements a button that call a function in the AppCentralManager where the bluetooth function will be implemented:

```m
- (IBAction) Scan{

NSLog(@"scan function");

[[AppBluetoothCenter alloc]initialize];

}
```

in the AppBluetoothCenter.h i've declaration those functions:

```m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CBService.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppBluetoothCenter : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property CBCentralManager* CentralManager;

- (void) initialize;

@end
```

in the AppBluetoothCenter.m i've implemented the functions:

```m
#import "AppBluetoothCenter.h"

@implementation AppBluetoothCenter

-(void)initialize{
NSLog(@"initialize");

_CentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff){
    NSLog(@"BLE OFF");
}
else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
    NSLog(@"BLE ON");
}
else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown){
    NSLog(@"NOT RECOGNIZED");
}
else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported){
    NSLog(@"BLE NOT SUPPORTED");
}
}
@end
```

Running app in the log console i receive:

*AppBluetooth[1273:60b] scan function

AppBluetooth[1273:60b] initialize*

Why centralManagerDidUpdateState it's not be called?

Comment: In which device you are running your app?

Comment: I've running on Iphone5 and Iphone4, both with iOS7

Comment: Only iPhone4S+ has the BLE support. Check whether https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html works for you.

Comment: I know that, the app is running also on an iphone5. But in any way if i run app in iPhone4 the result of central.state should be CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iphone4 - doesn't support bluetooth4 modules.
first device that support BLE is iPhone 4s

```
[[AppBluetoothCenter alloc]initialize];
```

i don't think it is a good idea to call initialize after alloc

system will call initialize for you.

> +initialize is a class method, run before any instances of the class are created and before other class methods are run. +initialize isn't
>   something you use most of the time, but it's handy for setting up any
>   static variables that the class as a whole might use, or for ensuring
>   that certain conditions are met before any instances are created.

so put your init code 
NSLog(@"initialize");

_CentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

in init method

i think thats the trouble

and use init

```
- (IBAction) Scan{
NSLog(@"scan function");
AppBluetoothCenter* bleCenter = [[AppBluetoothCenter alloc] init];
}
```

this is how my manager looks like
//H

```
#define DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK(block) \
static dispatch_once_t pred = 0; \
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil; \
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ \
_sharedObject = block(); \
}); \
return _sharedObject; \

@interface MWBluetoothManager : NSObject<CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
{}
+ (MWBluetoothManager *)sharedInstance;
-(void) startScan;
-(void) stopScan;
//..and other methods
@end
```

//M

```
+ (MWBluetoothManager *)sharedInstance {
    DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK(^{
        return [[self alloc] init];
    });
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _deviceList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _metaDataForDevices = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//        _vendor_name = {0};
        _libver = 0;
        _sendBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];        
    }
    return self;
}

-(CBCentralManager *)centralManager
{
    if (!_centralManager)
        _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    return _centralManager;
}
```

DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK

this is for singleton pattern, i most cases you don't need another instance of bluetooth manager in your application, so every time you call init it will return the same object, hope that helps

Comment: I use  [[AppBluetoothCenter alloc]initialize];  because i've an interface file AppBluetoothView, with the button, and in this way i can call the method in AppBluetoothCenter.  
AppBluetoothCenter* bleCenter = [[AppBluetoothCenter alloc] init];  don't permitt me to call the method initialize.

Comment: initialize, is not the method you need for setup BluetoothCenter, it is for static var. and other class var. not for instance of class. read about "load" and "initialize" methods

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the real reason, you can try

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) AppBluetoothCenter *appBluetoothCenter;
…………………………
- (IBAction) Scan{

NSLog(@"scan function");

appBluetoothCenter=[[AppBluetoothCenter alloc]initialize];

}
```